# linq compare list<string> to csv string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

How can we compare a list to csv string in the query to get the result?

```
 var q = _context.vBClaimDatas.AsQueryable();
 If (SingleProduct.Any())
  {
       List<string> str = SingleProduct.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
       q = q.Where(p => str.Contains(p.ProductIds));
  }
              
   var dq = (from v in q
   select new LegalSuitReport
   {
   SingleProduct=qs.SingleProduct(),
   ClaimNo = qs.ClaimNo,         
                            
  }).ToList().Select(qs => new LegalSuitReport()
   {
   SingleProduct=qs.SingleProduct(),
    ClaimNo = qs.ClaimNo,                   
                        
   }).ToList();
```

Example

```
      var str = new List<string> {  "1","2" }                
      p.products is "1,2,4,5,6"  valid
      p.products is "6"
      p.products is "6"
      p.products is "1,7"  valid
      p.products is "4"
      p.products is "2"    valid
```

Comment: `AsQueryable` is very rarely useful. It is almost certainly not useful here.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] so we can run the code on our end (easily).